# Applying Insufficient Explanation Post Notice to One-line Questions?

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, post-notices

Moderators currently have a tool to add a Post Notice that says:

> **insufficient explanation**
>
> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and
>   context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is
>   right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations
>   may be removed.

However, there seems to be no equivalent wording for one-line questions.

Could the wording be changed to something like below to cover both one line questions and one-line answers?

> **insufficient explanation**
>
> We're looking for longer posts that provide some explanation and context.
>
> - Don't just ask a one-line question; provide some background like a brief description of your research prior to asking
> - Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is
>     right, ideally with citations.
>
> Questions and answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Sometimes such questions can simply be closed for being unclear or too broad but on the two sites I moderate there is an aversion to closing questions from new users, so to give them some guidance about what is expected, without spending time writing the same comment over and over, a post notice like this would provide a good "couple of clicks" alternative.

Comment: Isn't this what closing is for?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards On the two sites I moderate there is an aversion to closing questions from new users, so to give them some guidance about what is expected, without spending time writing the same comment over and over, a post notice like this seemed like a good alternative.